# how to get class member object by it's string name?

Tags: objective-c

If I have a class member of lets say UIImageView in my viewcontroller :

```
UIImageView* imageView = self.memberImageView1;
```

Is there a way I can get this member by string ? somthing like :

```
UIImageView* imageView =[self.getMember(@"memberImageView1")];
```

Of course I'm talking about solution with objective-c syntax, and not custom.
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a String representing the name of a variable to set the variable.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680284/using-a-string-representing-the-name-of-a-variable-to-set-the-variable)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend [Key Value Coding](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html) before reflection.

```
UIImageView* imageView =[self valueForKey:@"memberImageView1"];
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about this

Comment: Ya thanks to isa swizzling and other fun things there are a lot of ways to access and set values on classes. I use these methods a lot for custom serialization. Check out some other methods like -[NSObject dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:] http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: That'll work, but it is very uncommon to do use this kind of loosely coupled pattern.  Certainly, can be done and there are uses, but you typically want to stick to tightly coupled patterns that can be fully validated by the compiler.

Comment: I agree, very error prone and should not be used when it can be avoided. I find it useful when I have a short amount of time to implement a lot of webservice calls and I need to serialize the data. I typically have a base class that knows when it is being serialized, checks for undefinedKeys during serialization and log in Debug mode, add the undefined keys/values to a dictionary, then after serialization I allow undefinedKeys to raise an exception by calling super.

Answer (score 1):

To do this kind of thing you can use reflection:

[Objective-C Runtime Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html)

The other way is to use a Dictionary with a string as a key pointing to the class variable.

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, a full-on *crazy* way to do this would be as follows:

```
UIImageView *imageView;

SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"memberImageView1");
NSMethodSignature *signature = [self instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:selector];
NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:signature];

[invocation setSelector:selector];
[invocation setTarget:self];
[invocation invoke];
[invocation getReturnValue:&imageView];
```

Please feel free to cross-post to the [Daily WTF](http://thedailywtf.com/).